# Align by the top borders of figures when using subcaption

Tags: floats, subcaption

I'm using the `subcaption`package to have figures side-by-side. The problem is that the package aligns the figures to their subcaptions (should I be taking a hint for the package name?) rather than the top of the pictures.

How can I algin the subfigures by the top border?

MWE:

```
\begin{figure}[h]
\begin{subfigure}[b]{.5\linewidth}
\centering\large A
\caption{A subfigure}\label{fig:1a}
\end{subfigure}%
\begin{subfigure}[b]{.5\linewidth}
\centering\large B
\caption{Another subfigure with a long, long, long, long caption.}\label{fig:1b}
\end{subfigure}
\caption{A figure}\label{fig:1}
\end{figure}
```

Result:
[image: Subcaption example]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've tried to solve the problem in a different way, although in the package documentation I don't find any hint on this. Instead of adopting `[b]` I set `[t]`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[h]
\begin{subfigure}[t]{.5\linewidth}
\centering\large A
\caption{A subfigure}\label{fig:1a}
\end{subfigure}%
\begin{subfigure}[t]{.5\linewidth}
\centering\large B
\caption{Another subfigure with a long, long, long, long caption.}\label{fig:1b}
\end{subfigure}
\caption{A figure}\label{fig:1}
\end{figure}    

\end{document}
```

that leads to:

[image]

The reason of my choice was just a parallel with `t,b` of `columns` alignment in `Beamer`.

Comment: Regarding the missing hint: It's "`the new environments subfigure and sub-table are available, which have the same (optional & mandatory) arguments as the minipage environment.`" in the documentation. Will try to make this more clear in the next version...

Comment: @AxelSommerfeldt: thanks! Now it's clear to me. :)

Comment: @AxelSommerfeldt: I couldn't figure it out for the life of me :)

Comment: @benregn This won't align the subcaptions to each other if the figures have different height.

Comment: @egreg: I'll keep that in mind. In the specific case that prompted the question, it is not a problem.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a trick that fools LaTeX into thinking that the first subcaption is as high as the second, but doesn't add to the width:

```
\subcaption{A subfigure\vspace{\baselineskip}}
```

Of course, leave this kind of adjustments for the final revision of the document, when you're sure that the text won't change any more.