# Aligning two pictures without subcaptions to the top with the subcaption package

Tags: graphics, vertical-alignment, subfloats

My problem is similar to this one:

[Align by the top borders of figures when using subcaption](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/56289/align-by-the-top-borders-of-figures-when-using-subcaption)

I want to align two pictures to the top. The solution given works fine for pictures with subcaptions. But my pictures should not have a subcaption, the two pictures shall only have one caption. So if I remove the subcaptions the pictures are not align to the top.

MWE:

```
documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article} 
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{tikz,pgf,pgfplots}  
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\usetikzlibrary{plotmarks,shapes,positioning,fit}
\pgfkeys{/pgf/number format/.cd ,use comma ,set thousands separator={.}} 
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{spy}
\usepgfplotslibrary{external}
\pgfkeys{/pgf/images/include external/.code=\includegraphics{#1}}
\tikzexternalize[prefix=tikzpdf/]% activate with a name prefix
\usepackage{filemod}
\newcommand{\includetikz}[2]{
\tikzsetnextfilename{#2}
\filemodCmp{tikzpictures/#1/#2.tex}{tikzpdf/#2.pdf}
    {\tikzset{external/remake next}}{}
    \input{tikzpictures/#1/#2.tex}  
            }
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[htb]
    \centering
    \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.35\textwidth}
        \centering
        %\caption{}
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{ort_unten}
        \label{fig:skizze_ort_unten}
    \end{subfigure}
    \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.55\textwidth}
        \centering
        %\caption{}
        \setlength{\fwidth}{\textwidth}
        \setlength{\fheight}{7cm}
        \includetikz{ort}{ort_unten}
    \end{subfigure}
    \caption{one picture (left) and a graph (right)}
    \label{fig:ort_unten}
\end{figure}   
\end{document}
```

This is the result:

[image: result]

Is there a possibility to fix this?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since `subfigure`s are `minipage`s, the following trick works: add `\vspace*{0pt}` just after each `\begin{subfigure}`.

MWE (I've used images from the `mwe` package since I don't have yours)

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{tikz,pgf,pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\usetikzlibrary{plotmarks,shapes,positioning,fit}
\pgfkeys{/pgf/number format/.cd ,use comma ,set thousands separator={.}}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{spy}
\usepgfplotslibrary{external}
\pgfkeys{/pgf/images/include external/.code=\includegraphics{#1}}
\tikzexternalize[prefix=tikzpdf/]% activate with a name prefix
\usepackage{filemod}
\newcommand{\includetikz}[2]{
\tikzsetnextfilename{#2}
\filemodCmp{tikzpictures/#1/#2.tex}{tikzpdf/#2.pdf}
    {\tikzset{external/remake next}}{}
    \input{tikzpictures/#1/#2.tex}
            }
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[htb]
    \centering
    \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.35\textwidth}
    \vspace*{0pt}
        \centering
        %\caption{}
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-a}
        \label{fig:skizze_ort_unten}
    \end{subfigure}
    \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.55\textwidth}
    \vspace*{0pt}
        \centering
        %\caption{}
        %\setlength{\fwidth}{\textwidth}
        %\setlength{\fheight}{7cm}
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-b}
    \end{subfigure}
    \caption{one picture (left) and a graph (right)}
    \label{fig:ort_unten}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Since I don't have the pictures you mention, I'm using some provided by [`mwe`](http://ctan.org/pkg/mwe). Since I'm unfamiliar with the inclusion-tactics of [`tikz`](http://ctan.org/pkg/pgf), I can only speculate whether this will work/not:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[htb]
  \centering
  \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.35\textwidth}
    \centering
    %\caption{}
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth,valign=t]{example-image-a}
    \label{fig:skizze_ort_unten}
  \end{subfigure}
  \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.55\textwidth}
    \centering
    %\caption{}
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth,height=7cm,valign=t]{example-image-b}
  \end{subfigure}
  \caption{one picture (left) and a graph (right)}
  \label{fig:ort_unten}
\end{figure}   
\end{document}
```

The idea is to use [`adjustbox`](http://ctan.org/pkg/adjustbox) with the `export` option. This adds `adjustbox` options to those provided by [`graphicx`](http://ctan.org/pkg/graphicx) allowing you to set the `v`ertical `align`ment for each image. I've chosen them both to align at the `t`op.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I think your solution will probably work. But for me it is easier to use my own command \includetikz and I do not know where to put the valign command in it. So for me it is easier to use the \vspace*{0pt} trick. But thanks anyway!

Comment: @user47091: You will most likely use `\pgfkeys{/pgf/images/include external/.code=\includegraphics[valign=t]{#1}}`.